# Prohibit Office365 group members from editing SharePoint layouts on Sharepoint Teams and Microsoft Teams

Tags: azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams

How do we avoid Office 365 group based Team channel or SharePoint Team guests/members from editing the SharePoint UI side of things (pages, navigation) while still participating in document library etc?  I'm more worried about guests, but team members can cause havoc too.

Example 1: Guests are included in Azure AD.  You create a new SharePoint Team site, which creates a new O365 group.  When you add Azure AD members and guests to this group, they can all edit the navigation / pages etc.  But we just want them to use the site as is.

Example 2: Guest access is on for Microsoft Teams.  You create a new Team, guests in Azure AD are included.  They use the web app, open the General Team channel and choose "Open in SharePoint".  At this point top navigation has the gear for Office 365 to add a page, site contents, site settings, etc.  They can do a lot of damage.

What step is necessary to add this restriction?  This looks to be the solution: 
https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-prevent-team-site-members-from-editing-sharepoint-pages/
But this is from a while back, and not part of the new Microsoft 365 admin UI.  Since these are brand new sites, I'm trying to create them as simply as possible without any artifacts or messing up new integration features.

If you have any ideas or have dealt with a similar situation, please advise.

### thanks!!

[Edit - here's what worked for me based on alphaz18 suggested answer]:

1) Directly on the entire site collection level eg tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/teamname/ edit site permission levels

[image] [image]
[image]

2) Remove some list permissions from "Edit": [Manage, add, edit, delete]. Submit.
[image]

3) Go back into "Edit" permission, at the bottom of this cloned permission, choose "Copy Permission Level", call new version (e.g.) "EditLists". RE-check the [add, edit, delete] options for this cloned permission level. Submit.

[image]

4) Go to a page you want edits to occur in (e.g.) Documents view (/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx). Click top right gear, choose "Library settings".  Click "Permissions for this document library".

[image][image]

5) Break inheritance.

[image]

6) For Members group edit user permissions, set to cloned permission (eg) "EditItems"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely change the permission levels for different users and groups in sharepoint online for msTeams Created Sharepoint sites and your own.

if you are a site collection owner, just click the gear on top, click site permissions.
then click advanced permissions, and you can have the classic permissions panel, then you click permission levels and create one that fits your needs, eg just allow them to add items from lists for example. or whatever it is you want to allow them to do. 
as long as you dont allow them to edit pages and such should be fine. 
then assign the permission level to either team members or add more groups or whatever you want.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hopefully this is what you're after, 
Regards,

Comment: Thanks - I went back to this link and followed the Option 1 steps explicitly: https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-prevent-team-site-members-from-editing-sharepoint-pages/
The only Site Pages were Home.aspx - I stopped inheriting, set it to read, but the members are still able to edit the left navigation (on the default Sharepoint Team template - Home, Conversations etc), and are still able to click the settings gear on top right and add a page, add an app etc.  All very frustrating.

Comment: instead of doing that for (site pages under site contents) , i would try just doing it directly on the entire site collection level eg tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/teamname/ . and since in the advanced menu you can't change the members group to read, what you can do is click permission levels, and change the edit permission level and remove a ton of the checked specific permissions and test that. you should be able to prevent a bunch of activity this way too.

Comment: Oh my god- you are my hero. Here's the key: Edit the Edit permission (directly on entire site as you said): Remove 3 list permissions from "Edit": [Manage lists, add items, edit items]. Submit. Now you've stopped blanket site abuse. Return to Edit permission, copy permission level (at bottom), call it EditItems (or whatever), check [add items, edit items] again. Submit.  Back on the site, go to Documents page. Click top right gear, choose "Library settings".  Click "Permissions for this document library". Break inheritance. For Members group edit user permissions, set to custom "EditItems" !